# Compare PDF documents with embedded links?

Tags: pdf

`diffpdf` shows the visual differences in two PDF documents. Since some PDF documents include hyperlinks is there a diff that handles those also?

[image: Screen shot diffpdf on lubuntu.]

Comment: `diffpdf` appears to be a Windows program. Are you looking for Windows suggestions?

Comment: @michael-mrozek not first choice.